# Intranet solution (enterprise portal) with trophies/achievements functionality?

Tags: intranet, enterprise-portal

Our company, a call center enterprise, is considering implementing a corporative intranet (enterprise portal). Not talking about all the basics functionalities a intranet must have, I am thinking of using one with achievements functionality, based on certain uses of the intranet, like commenting a news, updating user profile and so on. I am looking for a more *social* intranet.

I know Vindula and Igloo Software, but they don´t have such functionality.

Any help on this?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I'm afraid that's a bit too broad: one doesn't setup an intranet with "achievements" being the only requirement. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your question to fill the gaps. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Izzy, thanks for the tip, but i do not agree in this case. In this question, I narrowed the requirements to a single functionality that interests me. I´m not concerned, at this moment, in determine the other requirements. As I said in the question, "Not talking about all the basic funcionalities a intranet must have...".

Comment: Up to you, Bruno. But it's not just me, that's what our site's rules are – plus currently 3 more of our higher-rep users vote the same. Which means: one more, and your question would be "put on hold" as being "too broad". Instead of simply "voting", I decided to give you a pointer so you can prevent that.

Comment: completing... @Izzy, too broad? It´s exactly the opposite. I haven´t put bullet points, but the requirements are there (it´s just one, must be more? why?) and the statement is clear. NicholasRaoul gave a good answer, straight to the point and my question have 2 upvotes (am i reading right, right?). We can discuss this on meta, but, guys, don´t be so restrictive or this site won´t be so useful as it can be.

Comment: Please reopen. It is not too broad, actually the software packages that fit these requirements are very few. The closing is the cause of a misunderstanding: Bruno says "intranet" thinking of an enterprise portal, while the closers understand "intranet" as a local network. I edited the question to remove the ambiguity, so please everyone reopen, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Liferay](http://liferay.com/) does exactly this.

It is an [enterprise portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_portal), which means employees use it to receive company news, communicate with each other, build knowledge. Administators can choose the components that get displayed, for instance Wiki, Shared calendar, Document library, News feed, Blog, etc.

Participating will get employees **social activity points**. You can refine how many points are awarded for each particular action:

[image: Liferay social activity points refining]

Administrators can choose to make the leaders board public:

[image: Liferay social leaders board]

More social features: https://www.liferay.com/products/what-is-a-portal/social-apps-platform

Comment: Thanks @NicholasRaoul. I checked the Liferay website and, as far as I understood, this functionality is present in the Liferay Portal, not in the Social Office solution (which seems fit for enterprises). Social Activity Points is enable in the Social Office?

Comment: Indeed, this functionality is only in Liferay Portal, which is also fit for enterprises. Social Office is a different solution, for your particular need I would suggest Liferay Portal, but if you have time I encourage you to try the demos for both of them :-)